# My server has limited bandwidth when I send it data

Tags: networking

My 6 servers and I have a fiber connections. The servers are hosted on a different city. We both have well over 100Mbps upload and download. Speed tests indicates a good bandwidth. But when I try to send the servers some file (a single one) over TCP (random port) or SSH (scp), this is limited to ~1MBps.

**EDIT**: When I download from the servers, it it's very fast (my max speed 11MBps)

When my friends try this as well from different locations, they also are limited to ~1MBps. If we send concurrently, we have less than 1 MBps (the sum of rates being 1MBps).
I tried the servers on 2 different ISP, same behavior.

Servers are "Intel NUC" on Ubuntu 22.04, `ufw` is disabled, ISP says there's no QoL on their end. The servers do not run any service yet. `iftop` trafic is empty. I can't help but think it's a software issue.

How can I troubleshoot if this is indeed a **software** issue?

This is one of the servers speedtest result:
[image: server speedtest result]

This is my speedtest result:
[image: my speedtest result]

This is the test I am doing `scp -P $PORT $FILE $USER@$HOST:/dev/null`
[image: example of SSH transfer]

This is the result of ethtool:

```
Settings for enp1s0:
        Supported ports: [ TP    MII ]
        Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Full
        Supported pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Supported FEC modes: Not reported
        Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Full
        Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
        Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
        Link partner advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                             100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                             1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full
        Link partner advertised pause frame use: No
        Link partner advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Link partner advertised FEC modes: Not reported
        Speed: 1000Mb/s
        Duplex: Full
        Auto-negotiation: on
        master-slave cfg: preferred slave
        master-slave status: slave
        Port: Twisted Pair
        PHYAD: 0
        Transceiver: external
        MDI-X: Unknown
netlink error: Operation not permitted
        Link detected: yes
```

**EDIT1**:
This is the result of iperf3 from me to a server:

```
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate
[  5]   0.00-1.00   sec  2.05 MBytes  17.2 Mbits/sec                  
[  5]   1.00-2.00   sec  1.89 MBytes  15.8 Mbits/sec                  
[  5]   2.00-3.00   sec  2.01 MBytes  16.9 Mbits/sec                  
[  5]   3.00-4.00   sec  2.32 MBytes  19.4 Mbits/sec                  
[  5]   4.00-5.00   sec  2.75 MBytes  23.0 Mbits/sec                  
[  5]   5.00-6.00   sec  1.19 MBytes  10.0 Mbits/sec                  
[  5]   6.00-7.00   sec  2.49 MBytes  20.9 Mbits/sec                  
[  5]   7.00-8.00   sec  2.55 MBytes  21.4 Mbits/sec                  
[  5]   8.00-9.00   sec  1.64 MBytes  13.8 Mbits/sec                  
[  5]   9.00-10.00  sec  2.31 MBytes  19.4 Mbits/sec
```

**EDIT2**:
This video display a weird behaviour. When we open the `tcptrack` software, it "unleashes" the bandwidth. When we close the software, the bandwidth is "leashed" again.
https://youtube.com/shorts/zKkKa2ZPJ94?feature=share

**EDIT3**:
When I set the network in promiscuity mode, it resolves the issue. But I believe it's a bad idea...
`sudo ifconfig enp1s0 promisc`

Comment: This night simply be traffic shaping done by your ISP

Comment: Are you sure you're using MB and Mb correctly in your question? (It looks like you are, but since you're using both and they are different by a factor of ~10 I just want to check.)

Comment: Can you please update your question with the output of cat /etc/ssh/ssh_config and eventually ~/.ssh/config ?

Comment: or state how you are doing the TCP (non-SSH) test. Please also note that tools like `iperf3` on both sides can also do such test.

Comment: Note that these "speedtests" usually just measure the bandwidth from your system to the nearest (Ookla) server. Routes in-between are slightly ignored.

Comment: A.B: I tested the TCP by using the application I develop and measured the rate with `tcptrack`. I updated the question with the result of `iperf3`. We can see a ceiling at 20Mbps. 
Marcus: I tested with 2 ISP
MC68020: nothing relevant in these files

Comment: @doobdargent could you explain what you mean with "tested with two ISPs"?

Comment: I edited the question with a video link. This is the weirdest thing I've seen in my career so far

Comment: *My 6 servers and I* sounds like it should be a tv show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by downgrading the ethernet driver from r8169 to r8168. (Realtek)

```
sudo apt install r8168-dkms
sudo modprobe r8168
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `ethtool` dump had an issue that concerns me:

```
Auto-negotiation: on
```

This allows your NIC to negotiate the speed of transmission of bits across the wire with the "other end"
This negotiation takes place at the lowest, electric circuit level of the OSI 7 layer model. It's not logged.

It's intended to work on connections whose speed changes over time. That's not you.

But, sometimes the nodes fall into a "Autonegotiation Storm", where the two nodes constantantly exchange low level Speed negotiations, not packets.

You can use `ethtool` to turn OFF Autonegotiation:

```
sudo ethtool --change enp1s0 autoneg off
```

Read `man ethtool`.

Comment: I tried with `autoneg off`, it did not change the behaviour